# Ensure if it is Mutual Exclusion or not

Tags: c, operating-system

```
int turn =1
```

**Process 1**

```
If (turn != 0)                                      
{                                                        
 Critical_Region()           
 noncritical_region()                         
   turn = 0                                              
}
```

**Process2**

```
if (turn !=1) {
Critical_Region()
 noncritical_region()
turn =1
 }
```

Kindly tell me that if these two processes ensures that they are mutually exclusive or not?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a homework, then the answer to your question is - read the little book of semaphores http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/downey05semaphores.pdf